# Pandas Using .str on a dataframe filtered with .loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pad the `float(64)` values with some zeros in a column called `date_of_birth` within a dataframe called `drugs_tall`. `date_of_birth` contains some `NA`.

This was my initial idea:

```
drugs_tall.loc[drugs_tall['date_of_birth'].isnull() == False, ['date_of_birth']] = drugs_tall.loc[drugs_tall['date_of_birth'].isnull() == False, ['date_of_birth']].astype('int').astype('str').str.zfill(6)
```

However, this generates the error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I got around this by simply doing (**this works**):

```
drugs_tall.loc[drugs_tall['date_of_birth'].isnull() == False, ['date_of_birth']] = drugs_tall.loc[drugs_tall['date_of_birth'].isnull() == False, ['date_of_birth']].astype('int').astype('str')

drugs_tall['date_of_birth'] = drugs_tall['date_of_birth'].str.zfill(6)
```

Note that it is not possible to go directly to:

```
drugs_tall['date_of_birth'] = drugs_tall['date_of_birth'].str.zfill(6)
```

As this will generate the error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use 
np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

It is also not possible to change the data type without using .loc selection:

```
drugs_tall['date_of_birth'].astype('int').astype('str')
```

As this will give:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

Am I going about this in a strange way or misunderstanding how the dataframes work? I know my two line solution is reasonably brief, but I don't understand what makes the two line solution different from my initial idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column indexer should be a scalar `'dob'` instead of a list `['dob']`. This is why you find a dataframe as the output of your indexing operation. This makes some sense: a sequence of columns is interpreted as a dataframe, a scalar column gives a series.

For your task, you can use `pd.Series.notnull` together with `pd.DataFrame.loc`. Integer conversion is recommended in case Pandas is storing your values as `float`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dob': [np.nan, None, 11585, 52590]})

mask = df['dob'].notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'dob'] = df.loc[mask, 'dob'].astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(6)

print(df)

      dob
0     NaN
1     NaN
2  011585
3  052590
```

Comment: Wow that is so simple thank you! So when is it appropriate to use a list in the column indexer?

Comment: @KelleyBrady, When you want to operate on a dataframe, not a single series. Generally, for tasks where you are querying & updating a single series, don't use a list.